# Why are new Android features (Proto DataStore) still generating Java code and Not Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm investigation

```
implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.10.0"
```

via this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore/#0)

I do not understand why the associated DataStore generated classes are Java

I thought Google announced that Kotlin had replaced Java as the primary Android development language?

I was under the impression Kotlin had many advantages over Java

is the issue proto buffers do not support Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer that quickly!

According to codelab link you shared, If you visit [page 6](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore/#5) first line indicates something where your answer relies:

> Protocol buffers are a mechanism for serializing structured data. You
> define how you want your data to be structured once and then the
> compiler generates source code to easily write and read the structured
> data.

So, basically under the hood, library is using code generator plugin that generates classes required for protobuf to work with project. *(Yes, you can relate same thing with data-binding where you write code on xml and under the hood there's generated class that actually implements that logic for you)*

And that's the reason 'generated classes are in Java'. It has nothing to do with source in this context *(Java/Kotlin support to library)*. Anything written in Java will seamlessly work on Kotlin and vice versa *(Considering Android development context)*

*Side note: You can also relate it to annotation processor where we actually generate Java code based on annotation on any criteria.*